# Remove all rows in a CSV file which aren't starting with numbers in python

Tags: python, csv, copy

I want to remove all lines from a CSV file which don't start with a number. As far as I understood I can do that by creating a new  CSV file and I need to copy the desired rows from the input to the output file but when I execute my code, the output files separates every character with the default delimiter which in my case is `,` and it creates rows in the output file with `,` after every character. That's my code:

```
import os, sys, csv

input_dir = "/home/test/input/"

for csv_in in os.listdir(input_dir):
    if csv_in.lower().endswith('.csv') and not csv_in.lower().startswith('fixed_'):
        csv_infile = input_dir + csv_in
        csv_out = input_dir + "fixed_" + csv_in
        with open(csv_infile) as f, open(csv_out, 'wb') as f_out:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            writer = csv.writer(f_out)
            for row in f:
                if row.startswith(tuple('0123456789')):
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `file.write`

**Ex:**

```
import os

input_dir = "/home/test/input/"

for csv_in in os.listdir(input_dir):
    if csv_in.endswith('.csv') and not csv_in.lower().startswith('fixed_'):
        csv_infile = os.path.join(input_dir, csv_in)
        csv_out = os.path.join(input_dir, "fixed_" + csv_in)
        with open(csv_infile) as f, open(csv_out, 'wb') as f_out:
            for row in f:
                if row.startswith(tuple('0123456789')):
                    f_out.write(row)
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the condition `if row[0].isdigit():`, as this is clearly readable and could easily be expanded to more digits to be required (i.e.e.g.: `if row[:3].isdigit():`)

Comment: Perhaps one could add mentioning that `csv` isn't necessary here, as only full lines are copied or not depending on their beginning

Answer (score 0):

CSV behaviour is hard to debug when you do not share the same locale. 
Adding some debug output made clear that you should use the 'reader' iterator. In that case row contains a list of the comma-separated values. You then have to apply startswith to the first item of the list.

```
import os, sys, csv

input_dir = "/home/lc253481/src/python/"

for csv_in in os.listdir(input_dir):
    if csv_in.lower().endswith('.csv') and not csv_in.lower().startswith('fixed_'):
        csv_infile = input_dir + csv_in
        csv_out = input_dir + "fixed_" + csv_in
        with open(csv_infile, 'r') as f, open(csv_out, 'wb') as f_out:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                print row
                print len(row)
                if row[0].startswith(tuple('0123456789')):
                    writer.writerow(row)
```